# to send a text file to server using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to send a text file to server and get it saved. how can i do it using javascript???

Answer (score 2):

There are all sorts of security issues surrounding this. Would you be happy to visit a website that would upload a file from your machine to the server?

For a generic website, where users are likely to have their permissions set to deny this sort of access it isn't possible.

If by chance, you are looking to do this for an application where you have control over the security settings for its users, and that you can guarantee its Windows and IE, then it is possible by reading the file and passing the details by posting to the server. See the following link : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm

However when you move away from IE or Windows, then you are going to struggle.

Comment: hi, yes i want to visit a website that would upload a file from my machine to the server. but with the link u have provided its not clear for me. can u please get me some more details on how to do it??

Comment: Seriously? So, you would be happy for ANY website on the net to have the ability to upload ANY file from your machine? What if that website is trying to farm information about you? What about the bandwidth that you are paying for? That would just be....well....anarchy! :-) As, for "reading JavaScript files", try googling that phrase, and see if you get anything useful.

Comment: @JamesWiseman: just reading this now.  I think you missed the point.  I don't think he was requesting a website to search the machine with JS and automatically pull some file, but instead, upload a file through a website, using JS (this is what happens when you upload a photo to Facebook).  It is possible, using multipart/form-data; generally the recipient is a php/perl script that controls the file size and stores the file somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

using ajax of course.

have a file on the server, PHP or ASP - depending on what your internet server is.
this file will accept the text file (data and name), and should also check for size and if this file already exists or not, and if all is ok-  it will save it, and return a string "OK"

on the client, javascript side, just send the information to the server using ajax, or HTTPREQUST object - there's plentty of documentation for that around. and if you get back a response of "OK" then you know that it sent well.
even better: don't use HTTPREQUEST, but do dynmaic script tag insertion - where the source attribute of the script you're appending is that file on the server like:

```
var a = document.createElement('script');
a.type = 'text/javascript';
a.src = "http://server/serverFile.PHP?filename=XXX&data=LONG STRING OF DATA REPRESTING THE DATA TO BE SAVED PROBABLY LESS THAN 2K IN SIZE AND ALSO YOU SHOULD ESCAPE OR ATLEAST URIENCODE IT";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

and on the server file, serverFILE.PHP:

```
    <?php
    // some code to save the request variable [data].
    // if all is ok:
    alert("ok")
    // or:
    result = "ok"
?>
```

get it?

note: you'll probably have a limit of less than 2K on the file size.

Comment: in the example what u have give i need to specify the file data explicitly. i dont want to do that as file data may vary. in this what to do???

Comment: just do something like url = "http://server/serverFile.PHP?filename=XXX&data=" + encodeURIComponent (YOURDATA)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a front-end language. You may use php or any server side language.

Comment: my problem is, i want to write a html page which uploads text files to server from client side. is it possible using javascript?? from client side i cant use PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Ajax equiv function make an iframe with width and height=0px then make it the target of the form with the file upload input and process it with the action PHP

```
<form action="upload.php" target="target" method="post"
name="uploadform" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="input_file_upload">Upload:</label>
  <input onchange="document.uploadform.submit();" size="80"
  type="file" name="file_upload[]" id="file_upload"
  multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fileUpload" value="upload" />
  <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<iframe id="target" name="target" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
</iframe>
```